# CSS table layout with n rows and expanding as columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have been struggling with this CSS layout. I have `n` items that its amount might increase dynamically. And I want to only just have `n` rows and many or unlimited columns layout.

So, let's say that `n` is **2** and I have **3** items, This is how my items should look like,

```
-----------
| 1 || 3 |
-----------
| 2 |
-----------
```

For the same `n`, with **6** items,

```
-----------------
| 1 || 3 || 5 |
-----------------
| 2 || 4 || 6 |
-----------------
```

*And so on..*

I have tried tinkering it with `float: left` with no lucks. And now I am kinda learning flex layout, which leads me to stuck.

Please help :) Here's my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7j3ta04u/2/)

*Note: All my items will have the same `width` and `height`.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[**jsFiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/xzo6298j/1/)

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
/* Below this is just styling */

.items {
  background-color: #0f9c8a;
  padding: 4px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
}
.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #6f6ac2;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  margin: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    Item 1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 3
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 4
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 5
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Update:** since you need to align the `.item` divs to the left just add `align-content:flex-start;` to the container `.items`, like this:

[**jsFiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/xzo6298j/3/)

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
/* Below this is just styling */

.items {
  background-color: #0f9c8a;
  padding: 4px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 1000px;
}
.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #6f6ac2;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  margin: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    Item 1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 3
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 4
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 5
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it's something like that.. But does the `.items` width have to be `100%` instead of in `px`? Is it also possible for them to align them to left? I have tried using `justify-content` without luck as well.. And is the row number can only be set by the height of `.items`? I am sorry, really newb in flex here..

Comment: Not at all, you certainly can use fixed width, in this [demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzo6298j/2/) width of `.items` is set to `1000px`, give me some time to check the aligning please

Comment: Oh, I had `2500px` before, I thought that it didn't work. So it appears that 3rd and the rest of items were actually there.. My bad..

Comment: if you add `align-content:flex-start;` to the `.items` it will be aligned to the left as in this [demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzo6298j/3/)

Comment: You're welcome and I'm glad it helped, enjoy coding!